# How do I compare the trait type with the string type in substrate module?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I want the user to input the address `to:T::AccountIdAccountId`, and it will compare to the address that I set `let disable_address = "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY";`. My question is how do I compare those two different types? `if (receiver != disable_address)`, thanks.

***My code***

```
use frame_support::{decl_storage, decl_module, dispatch::DispatchResult};
use frame_system::ensure_signed;

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as VerifiableCreds {
        storeValue: u32;
    }
}

decl_module! {
  pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
    #[weight = 0]
      fn verify(origin, to:T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult
      {
        let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        let receiver = to;
        let disable_address = "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY";
      
        if (receiver != disable_address)
        {
          //do something         
        }
        Ok(())
      }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have provided is an SS58 representation of an address, which is not a good starting point for doing comparison.

You should instead convert the SS58 into its byte/hex representation:

Using: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/

```
5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY

> 0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
```

Then you want to compare the encoded version of the `AccountId` and see if it matches the byte form of the hex above:

```rust
let account_bytes: Vec<u8> = to.encode();
let match_bytes: Vec<u8> = hex_literal::hex!["d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"].into();

if account_bytes == match_bytes { ... }
```

Something like that... but in general, I would never recommend writing code this way. To start, you make an assumption about your Runtime that your accounts are of a certain format. Imagine another chain which uses a different account format, like the Ethereum 20 byte representation rather than a 32 byte representation. Any hardcoded logic like this would fail to work.

Instead, you should provide a configuration trait:

```
type DisableAddress: Get<Self::AccountId>;
```

Then you should do the match like so:

```
if to == T::DisableAddress::get() { ... }
```

Then you would do the same byte conversion logic I showed above within the runtime.

There is a good example of exactly this in this PR for the Purchase Pallet: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1369/files#diff-e5e76e02c0d16e79c70b024cbe3c6ea56f3249382a0f987ba203c34fcb40ed66R954

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, it's so helpful. The reason why I hardcoded the logic because I want to test whether it can disable the specific address to make the transfer(implement the balances pallet) in my new module if it violates our rule. But I think what I'm doing is useless because the account still can transfer through the balance pallet.

Comment: What you can do is create a filter so that users cannot call balances pallet directly, then the only way to transfer would be with your pallet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are there any resources I can reference?

Comment: Yes, do the opposite of this PR: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1443/files

Comment: Really appreciate~

Comment: String to Hex:
`5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY`  -> `0x3547727776614546357a58623236467a397263517044575335374374455248704e6568584350634e6f48474b75745159`
AccountId to Hex:
`5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY`  -> `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`   Why are they different?